# Integrated Authentication on dynamic/embedded Webresource.axd under IIS6

Tags: c#, security, iis-6, webresource

Is it possible to force Integrated Authentication on a dynamically created embedded resource under IIS6?

For those of you who don't know what a Webresource.axd is...it's the dynamically created resource from when you choose embedded "Embedded Resource" under build action in Visual Studio and then reference the resource using this syntax under your AssemblyInfo class.

[assembly: WebResource("namespace.fileName.png", "image/png")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone has a better answer, I'm thinking it is NO.